# How to revert a merge which is in between two merges

Tags: svn, version-control, project-management

I have a Trunk.
There are 3 branches created from the trunk, say `B1`, `B2` and `B3`.
From `B1`, merge and commit to Trunk was performed on say, 01-12-2011.
From `B2`, merge and commit to Trunk was performed on, 02-12-2011.
From `B3`, merge and commit to Trunk was performed on, 03-12-2011.

Now I want to revert changes of `B2` from Trunk without affecting `B1` and `B3`.

Please advise how to achieve it.

Please note that, if same file is modified in `B2` and `B3`, then reverting those files to the version created after merge of `B1` will lose changes from `B3`.

Comment: Which SVNclient are you using, TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are using TortoiseSVN,**

1. Checkout a copy of trunk.
2. Open revision log dialog.
3. Select the revision in which you have committed the B2 branch
4. Right click and in context menu click "Revert changes from this revision"

A [Detailed action guide is here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html). 
Search for "Revert changes from this revision" section on this page.